# CSS class not applying to element

Tags: css, leaflet

As mentioned in [this](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/143#issuecomment-224057041) answer, I am trying to apply a grayscale property to a class in leafletjs, but it does not get applied to it.
If I use the Chrome developer tools to navigate to the element with that class and apply the same grayscale property in Chrome dev tools, it gets applied.
I tried setting the properties to `!important` as well, but to no effect, what am I doing wrong.

Here's the css code,

```
.leaflet-tile-pane {
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
```

}

Comment: A little more code would have helped - did you check the 'compute tab', which is next to the styles tab... search for the filter property in the list of all properties which are applied... there you'll see the class(es) which override your !important... that'll help you pinpoint the exact reason for grayscale not being applied

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Would posting here the html code of the element help?

Comment: not exactly... in your code there is probably a class (or inline CSS) which is over-riding your !important... looking into the chrome developer tools will help you pin-point that... this will be a great learning experience also; else you can share the code which reproduce the problems and the stack overflow community can help.

Comment: The map is being rendered with leafletJs, and the image tiles ( and its html elements) are dynamically fetched when the page is loaded.